# Is 256-bit BitLocker encryption really 256-bit?

Tags: bitlocker

It might sound like a silly question, but clearly I'm not getting something. I've enabled 256-bit encryption in group policy settings and encrypted a drive. `manage-bde -status` says `Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 256`. But the recovery key is still 48 digits long. Since every sixth digit is a checksum, it gives us 10^40 (about 2^133) combinations. Doesn't this make the encryption key effectively 133 bits long?